# In-place C++ implementation of QR-decomposition via Householder transformation

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, matrix, in-place

(Result: a couple of functions `orhtonormalize` and `forward_transformation` from [here](https://github.com/tomilov/quickhull/blob/master/include/quickhull.hpp) is resulting tested Householder method's implementation).

I'm trying to implement the Householder algorithm for QR decomposition of rectangular matrix? *In-place* means, that input is modified during computations and diagonal of upper-triangular matrix *R* provided additionally as it introduced in [the article](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gander/papers/qrneu.pdf) on page 12 (or something alike, but space-efficient). An implementations of the *tred2* function (widely presented in Internet) are not quite clear. My intention is to implement (or to obtain some ready to use implementation of the) Householder transformation in pure *C++*.

This is the result of my own efforts. It is a naive straight reimplementation of the MATLAB code from mentioned article, and (therefore) it gives mostly wrong output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <limits>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

using value_type = long double;
using vector = std::valarray< value_type >;
using matrix = std::valarray< vector >;

std::ostream &
operator << (std::ostream & out, matrix const & matrix)
{
    for (vector const & point : matrix) {
        for (value_type const & x : point) {
            out << x << ' ';
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }
    return out;
}

value_type const eps = std::numeric_limits< value_type >::epsilon();
value_type const zero = value_type(0);
value_type const one = value_type(1);

int
main()
{
    matrix qr{{12, 6, -4},
              {-51, 167, 24},
              {4, -68, -41}};
    std::cout << qr << std::endl;

    std::size_t const m = qr[0].size();
    std::size_t const n = qr.size();
    vector rtrace(zero, n);
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) { // Householder itself
        value_type norm = zero;
        vector & qr_j = qr[j];
        for (std::size_t i = j; i < m; ++i) {
            value_type const & qrij = qr_j[i];
            norm += qrij * qrij;
        }
        using std::sqrt;
        norm = sqrt(norm);
        value_type & qrjj = qr_j[j];
        value_type & dj = rtrace[j];
        dj = (zero < qrjj) ? -norm : norm;
        using std::abs;
        value_type f = norm * (norm + abs(qrjj));
        assert(eps < f);
        f = one / sqrt(std::move(f));
        qrjj -= dj;
        for (std::size_t k = j; k < m; ++k) {
            qr_j[k] *= f;
        }
        for (std::size_t i = j + 1; i < n; ++i) {
            vector & qr_i = qr[i];
            value_type dot_product = zero;
            for (std::size_t k = j; k < m; ++k) {
                dot_product += qr_j[k] * qr_i[k];
            }
            for (std::size_t k = j; k < m; ++k) {
                qr_i[k] -= qr_j[k] * dot_product;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "output:\n" << qr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "diagonal of R: " << std::endl;
    for (value_type const & rd : rtrace) {
        std::cout << rd << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    matrix q{{1, 0, 0},
             {0, 1, 0},
             {0, 0, 1}};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        vector & qi = q[i];
        std::size_t j = n;
        while (0 < j) {
            --j;
            vector & qr_j = qr[j];
            value_type s_ = zero;
            for (std::size_t k = j; k < m; ++k) {
                s_ += qr_j[k] * qi[k];
            }
            for (std::size_t k = j; k < m; ++k) {
                qi[k] += qr_j[k] * s_;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Q:\n" << q << std::endl << std::endl;
    matrix r{{0, 0, 0},
             {0, 0, 0},
             {0, 0, 0}};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        r[i][i] = rtrace[i];
        for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            r[j][i] = qr[j][i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << "R:\n" << r << std::endl << std::endl;
    matrix a{{0, 0, 0},
             {0, 0, 0},
             {0, 0, 0}};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            a[j][i] += q[i][j] * r[i][j];
        }
    }
    std::cout << "regenerated input:\n" << a << std::endl << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [Matrix Computations](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Computations-Hopkins-Studies-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/0801854148) by Golub and van Loan? It's my go-to reference for this sort of thing, but unfortunately I don't have my copy to hand to see what it says on the subject.

Comment: Looking on Google Books, you want section "5.2.2 Householder QR" of Golub and van Loan. It covers this very nicely. I once implemented that algorithm and remember it being rather straightforward.

Comment: @NPE thank you, I'll look through this paper.

Comment: @NPE Sadly it is not memory-efficient version of the Householder algorithm.

Comment: Fair enough, it sounds like you're ahead of me there (I neither have the book to hand, nor this is fresh in my memory).

Comment: IIRC, it might be implemented as `qr_econ` (QR economical) in C++ matrix library Armadillo

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux The prototype of the function `qr_econ( Q, R, X )` talks me about no-in-place-nature of the function. I think it is economical in some other sense than memory-efficiency.

Comment: @Orient `qr_econ` declared as being `This function implements a memory-efficient QR for a non-square X that has dimensions m x n.`, I just looked into the source. But I recognize you need better than that

Comment: Check out the [DGEQRF function of LAPACK](http://www.netlib.no/netlib/lapack/double/dgeqrf.f) which does exactly this. This is an in-place implementation, the only permanent addition storage required is for a small vector of scale factors. LAPACK is written in Fortran, but you should be able to glean the relevant parts of the algorithm from the code. Note that QR decomposition by Householder reflection is not unique, because there are two equivalent choices for every reflection. For a C implementation (from scratch) that I wrote in the past I figured out how to match DGEQRF.

Comment: @njuffa I read, that the right choise is sole. Just one choise of the sign at each step leads to numerical stability.

Comment: @Orient: That is not my recollection, but it has been some time since I worked on this, so I don't want to swear to it. As I recall, my initial C implementation from first principles was in fact numerically stable, but my solutions often started to diverge from DGEQRF to the right of some random column. The starting point for my work was the book by Golub and van Loan that has been already mentioned.

Comment: @Orient: Regarding the numerical stability of the two possible choices for the sign for each reflection, the following papers are relevant, as they demonstrate that choosing either sign is fine as long as the computation is properly arranged: Beresford N. Parlett, "Analysis of algorithms for reflections in bisectors". SIAM Review, Vol. 13, No. 2 (1971), pp. 197-208. B. Danloy, "On the choice of signs for Householder's matrices". J. Comp. Appl. Math., Vol. 2, No. 1 (1976), pp. 67-69